# Is it possible to add media queries to JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I would like to know if it's possible to use media queries in javafx. I have a button that is an image in a gridpane and when I use another resolution for my application, the gridpane adapts to the new resolution, but the button, which is an image, does not adapt.

code:

```
//gridpane
GridPane gridPaneStart = new GridPane();
gridPaneStart.setHgap(2);
gridPaneStart.setVgap(2);
gridPaneStart.prefWidthProperty().bind(window.widthProperty());
gridPaneStart.prefHeightProperty().bind(window.heightProperty());
gridPaneStart.setGridLinesVisible(true);
ColumnConstraints column1 = new ColumnConstraints();
column1.setPercentWidth(70);
ColumnConstraints column2 = new ColumnConstraints();
column2.setPercentWidth(50);
ColumnConstraints column3 = new ColumnConstraints();
column3.setPercentWidth(50);
gridPaneStart.getColumnConstraints().addAll(column1, column2, column3);   
RowConstraints row1 = new RowConstraints();
row1.setPercentHeight(60);
RowConstraints row2 = new RowConstraints();
row2.setPercentHeight(20);
RowConstraints row3 = new RowConstraints();
row3.setPercentHeight(20);
gridPaneStart.getRowConstraints().addAll(row1, row2, row3);   
//background
ImageView background = new ImageView("/images/start_background.png");
background.fitWidthProperty().bind(window.widthProperty());
background.fitHeightProperty().bind(window.heightProperty());
//startknop
Image startButtonShadow = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/start_button.png"));
Image startButtonNoShadow = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/start_button_no_shadow.png"));
Button startKnop = new Button();
startKnop.setGraphic(new ImageView(startButtonShadow));
startKnop.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            getScene().setRoot(new KeuzeSpelers());
        }
    });
gridPaneStart.add(startKnop, 1, 1);
//op scherm tonen
this.getChildren().addAll(background, gridPaneStart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently it is not possible to use media queries in JavaFX CSS.

There is an issue still open: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091994

From the [CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html):

> Beginning with JavaFX 8u20, the CSS @import is also partially
>   supported. Only unconditional import is supported. In other words, the
>   media‑type qualifier is not supported.